# How to run Ocean test with Petrel demo project

Tags: c#, ocean

I am trying run a Ocean test framework test where I open the Petrel 2011 demo project. However, when I open the project with `PetrelSystem.ProjectService.OpenPrimaryProject()` I get the following error message and the test is aborted:

```
Error: File EclipseNamesToPropertyTypeCatalog.xml not found in the installation
File EclipseNamesToPropertyTypeCatalog.xml not found in the installation
Slb.Ocean.Petrel.ProjectOpenException : Could not open the project.
----> Petrel_Framework_NS.TestAssertionException : File EclipseNamesToPropertyTypeCatalog.xml not found in the installation
at Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Core.Impl.Core.ProjectService.OpenPrimaryProject(String projectPath)
at Slb.Ocean.Petrel.ProjectService.OpenPrimaryProject(String path)
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment, but I need 50 rep first.

Does it work when running the test directly with nunit.exe (from the Petrel installation folder)?

Does your test or project involve Eclipse at all?  If not, you may be able to comment out Eclipse related modules from petrel.exe.config.  Not a solution, but a suggested workaround.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseNamesToPropertyTypeCatalog.xml is deployed with Petrel under the xml folder. Apparently the working directory is different so that the file is not found.

Comment: I am running the tests using Resharper. In the Resharper options dialog I have specified that the tests should run from C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\Petrel 2011.  I have verified in the code that this is in fact the Environment.CurrentDirectory. How is the xml file located? Is Ocean2011Home used? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a work around. In order to run the demo project you need to configure the petrel environment variables correctly so they open the pre-configured demo project.

This can be done by setting the the PetrelTestProjectRoot and PetrelTestProject environment variables to the appropriate paths

Answer (score 0):

This answers is about Visual Studio testers (not verified on Resharper tester but the essence should be similar).

Looks like Petrel loads these .xml files based on the calling assembly path, e.g if a tester is loading Petrel, these files need to be in the same path as the tester.

One of the workaround is to copy (or making a Symbolic link to) the files to the folder of the tester exe. E.g. in VS2012:

[image: Files copied to the tester exe path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAjLv.png)

This applies to other versions of Visual Studio too.